# I imported an obj file into Blender and cannot add an uv wrap from a png file

Tags: import, uv-image-editor, file-format, object-mode, vector-mapping

I'm use to modeling in Fusion 360 and then export the file into an obj. I practically use Blender as a rendering tool because Fusion isn't as powerful.

Overall still learning how to model in Blender but in a meantime would like to know how I can add an uv wrap from a png file onto an imported obj model.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you must *unwrap* the .OBJ, (wavefront). You can do this by going to Edit Mode, selecting all of the faces by hitting 'A' on the keyboard, and pressing 'U' to unwrap. Then select *unwrap* or *smart UV unwrap* in the options drop down menu you get when hitting U, and you are done with the first step. The next step is to select a texture. By the way, you must be in Blender Cycles render mode to continue. Once you set your renderer to Cycles, go to the material settings for the object in the *properties* tab. Select whatever material you want for the object, and set the color to *image texture*. Then you can import your texture by clicking the file icon next to the image texture settings.

Answer (score 1):

[image: uv unwrap]

select your mesh press TAB to go into EDIT MODE

- Select EDGE SELECTION select edges to cut Press W click "Mark Seam"
- press A to select all
- press U to unwrap

or

- in edit mode press A
- press U
- select "Smart UV project"
- after this apply your material or image texture